# Compile from String using function arguments

Tags: compile

I want to return a `Compile`d function built from a string that uses values of local variables:

```
f[x_] := Module[{code},
    code = "Compile[{},x,CompilationTarget->\"C\"]";
    ToExpression[code]
];
```

While `f[1]` is a compiled function, `f[1][]` yields an error due to `x`.

Plain use of `Compile` works:

```
g[x_] := Module[{},
    Compile[{}, x, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
];
```

with `g[1][]` returning `1`.

Why does the compilation from string not recognize the local variable?

PS: I can work around this by inserting `ToString[x,InputForm]` into the string, but would like to understand better what happens.

PPS: In the original code, both parameters and code string are more involved.

Comment: Why must you use strings? `f[x_] := Module[{code}, code = Hold[Compile[{}, x, CompilationTarget -> "C"]]; ReleaseHold[code]]`

Comment: @J.M. I do not have to use strings, but it was natural to use them: The actual code is generated programmatically; in particular, some of the code _structure_ depends on parameters, while other parts are boilerplate code. Strings offered a simple way to avoid redundancy and assemble the code to be compiled.

Comment: Judicious use of `With[]` for insertion, along with `Hold[]`/`ReleaseHold[]` seems to me a more flexible way to go about it. You might be interested in looking up past [tag:meta-programming] questions.

Comment: try `Evaluate[x]` in your string (sory untested)

Comment: @george2079 Replacing `code` with `"Compile[{},Evaluate[x],CompilationTarget->\"C\"]";` does not help.

Comment: I expect you realize but to be sure your compiled code is attempting to reference a global symbol `x` which does not exist. If you do `x=3;f[1][]` you get `3`. (Not useful, but it should help see whats going on.).

Comment: @george2079 Yes, this appears to be about controlling scope and evaluation order.

Comment: @J.M. The `With` part of your suggestion is giving me trouble. I need to insert blocks of code that refer to variables defined in some template code. `block = ...some code here using x and y...; template = ...other code defining y; block; more code...; return compiled template`. Could you provide a small example like in your first comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that J.M.s advice to avoid using strings for that kind of meta-programming is the best answer you can get for that question. Looking up the meta-programming question to gather ideas how you can better tackle your specific problem is certainly worth the effort, for completeness here is his suggestion for your simplified example once more:

```
f[x_] := Module[{code},
   code = Hold[Compile[{}, x, CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
   ReleaseHold[code]
];
```

If you are new to Mathematica or have done similar things in other languages, you might think it is easier to manipulate strings but in Mathematica (and other homoiconic languages) it is in fact easier and much safer to manipulate held expressions. Due to its powerful pattern matcher Mathematica makes many of these tasks quite easy, although it sometimes is a bit tricky to handle evaluation order correctly.

You have also asked why your string approach doesn't work. To understand that you have to understand that at a deeper level a function definition in Mathematica is nothing but a definition of a global replacement rule. So evaluating a function will essentially insert the arguments **literally** into the RHS of the function definition and then evaluate the result. So you can think of function evaluation of some function definition like:

```
f[x_]:=Sin[Pi*x]
```

that `f[5]` will actually do something like:

```
ReleaseHold[With[{x=5},Hold[Sin[Pi*x]]]]
```

or

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[f[5]] /. f[x_] :> Sin[Pi*x]]
```

This will even work for any symbol with `Hold` attributes, as this example illustrates:

```
f[x_]:=Hold[x]
f[1]
```

With this picture in mind, it does probably not come as a surprise that inserting into strings does not work. This is one of the many reasons why doing meta-programming with strings is usually not the best solution.

If you really decide to go with strings (which I wouldn't suggest) you should realize that what you actually want to do here is to insert a constant into the code to compile -- when working with strings that is more like filling a string template than actually using a variable. Here is what I would do in that case:

```
f[x_] := Module[{code},
  code = "Compile[{},`x`,CompilationTarget->\"C\"]";
  ToExpression[TemplateApply[code, <|"x" -> x|>]]
];
```

Comment: The string solution is essentially what I do right now. The `With` solution is still giving me trouble. In the actual code, I need to insert blocks of code that refer to variables defined in a template code. Schematically, `block = ...code using x and y...; template = ...code defining y; block; more code...; return compiled template`. Could you provide an example for the With/Hold/ReleaseHold approach that does that?

Comment: The string-based equivalent would be `f[x_] := Module[{template, code, block},
        block = StringReplace["z = y*#x#;", "#x#" -> ToString[x, InputForm]]; 
        template = "Compile[{}, Module[{y,z}, y = 2; #block# z], CompilationTarget->\"C\"]";
        code = StringReplace[template, "#block#" -> block];
        ToExpression[code]
    ];` for which `f[3][]` yields `6`.

Comment: @mrupp, that should probably have been a separate question, but: `f[x_] := Block[{template, block, y, z}, block = Hold[Unevaluated[z = y x]];
  template = Hold[Compile[{}, Module[{y, z}, y = 2; #; z], CompilationTarget -> "C"]] &; template @@ block // ReleaseHold]`. Note the use of `Block[]` (*dynamic scoping*).

Comment: @mrupp: I think J.M. is right in suggesting to make this an own question which probably could refer to this one and should contain your string-based code so people have something to start with. I think that question could trigger some interesting answers...

Comment: I created a separate question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134911/metaprogramming-creating-compiled-functions-from-inter-dependent-code-blocks